# Real implementation where sizeof(size_t) < sizeof(unsigned int)

Tags: c, sizeof, size-t

I know that the C standard allows for implementations where

```
(sizeof(unsigned) > sizeof(size_t))
```

or

```
(sizeof(int) > sizeof(ptrdiff_t))
```

is true. But are there any real implementations where one of these is true?

**Background**

I wrote a function similar to `asprintf()` (since `asprintf()` is not portable), and `snprintf()` return an `int` but needs a `size_t` argument, so should I check if `leni` (shown below) is not less than `SIZE_MAX` in this code?

```
va_copy(atmp,args)
int leni = vsnprintf(NULL,0,format,atmp); //get the size of the new string
va_end(atmp);
if(leni<0)
  //do some error handling
if(leni>=SIZE_MAX) //do i need this part?
  //error handling
size_t lens = ((size_t)leni)+1;
char *newString = malloc(lens);
if(!newString)
  //do some error hanling
vsnprintf(newString,lens,format,args)!=lens-1)
```

Comment: I'm not sure that's actually possible, otherwise `sizeof(char[LARGE_NUMBER])` wouldn't always work.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth It do not allways work, if you write something like char str[1024ULL*1024ULL*1024ULL*5];, you will get a compile error on 32bit machines (at least in my case with gcc -m32) (but not on AMD64)

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth It doesn't have to. If the constant-expression in the brackets makes an object that cannot be represented by size_t, which will be the result of sizeof, then the compiler will generate an error.

Comment: @2501 - Off-topic: What about if the array size is passed via a variable (i.e. if it's a VLA type)?  Presumably would have to be a runtime-error / UB.

Comment: Use a static assertion.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth I'd say it would be undefined behavior when it is evaluated by sizeof.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth: You should get a truncation warning. If not: That's why one should enable warnings. C does not keep you from shooting you foot, though.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth, if you pass the len to a functin and creat there a array of that size (without malloc()), you will get a stack overflow in the most case  much faster than (U)INT_MAX or SIZE_MAX

Comment: @12431234123412341234123: "stack" is no concept in C.

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 - Oh, to clarify, I meant something like `long x = LARGE_NUMBER; sizeof(char[x]);` - so no explicit array creation.

Answer (score 3):

While the standard doesn't forbid that INT_MAX won't be smaller than SIZE_MAX, the function vsnprintf guarantees that the returned value will not be greater than SIZE_MAX.

If the functions succeeds, then the return value must be less than its second argument<sup>1</sup>. This argument has the type size_t, thus the return value must be less than SIZE_MAX.<sup>2</sup>.

And if you're not convinced, you can always use preprocessor directive that evaluates INT_MAX > SIZE_MAX, and then include the needed code that checks the result of vsnprintf.

---

<sup>1</sup> The identifier n mentioned in the standard citation below, is the second argument to vsnprintf.

<sup>2</sup> (Quoted from: ISO/IEC 9899:201x 7.21.6.12 The vsnprintf function 3)
The vsnprintf function returns the number of characters that would have been written
had n been sufficiently large, not counting the terminating null character, or a neg ative
value if an encoding error occurred. Thus, the null-terminated output has been
completely written if and only if the returned value is nonnegative and less than n.

Comment: Sorry if i dont understand you 100%. But if you set n to 0, (what i do) the returned Number must not be equal or less than n, so could it not be that the returned value is greater than SIZE_MAX?

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 Standard implies that return value must not be greater than n, which has a limit of SIZE_MAX. If you think the ruling is too vague to be reliable, just add the check that is guarded by preprocessor directives and forget about it.